# Time each command in my shell startup file

Tags: shell, zsh

My shell startup file (`.bashrc`, which I run for zsh as well) has gotten really slow for interactive shells. In typical lazy-programmer fashion, I'd like to set up a trap to time each command in that file and print out the slow ones so I can see where to optimize. I've tried this:

```sh
last_ts=0
last_command=''
timediff () {
    ts=$(date +%s.%N)
    delta=$(($ts-$last_ts))
    if [[ $last_ts > 0 && $delta > 0.1 ]]; then
        echo "$last_command" took $delta sec
    fi
    last_command="$BASH_COMMAND"
    last_ts=$ts
}
trap timediff DEBUG
```

and this *almost* works, except it doesn't print the command name. I suspect this is because $BASH_COMMAND isn't a thing in zsh. How can I get the name of the current command in zsh?

Comment: Stop using `.bashrc` with `zsh`, and put valid `zsh` code in `.zshrc`.

Comment: My `.zshrc` invokes my `.bashrc`, which is designed to be generic over all common shells.

Comment: Running `date` is itself expensive enough to slow down execution very significantly. I'd strongly advise against the approach you're using here; better to enable `set -x` and time output's appearance (with a tool in a language that isn't running a whole new process every time it wants to collect a timestamp; it's trivial to pipe through an awk script for the job, f/e).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes, that's true... any ideas on my question?

Comment: BTW, `[[ $delta > 0.1 ]]` almost certainly does not do what you want -- it's a *string* comparison, not a *numeric* comparison.

Comment: Re: "ideas on the question", I already gave you the approach I would, myself, follow if given someone else's dotfiles and instructed to trace them -- to enable `set -x` logging (ideally with a `PS4` that logs filename and line number for each instruction) and pipe the FD with the trace logs through an `awk` script that puts a timestamp on each line.

Comment: The `set -x` method doesn't really work, because it also prints every line of every file sourced from my main rc file. (It was the first thing I tried.) I'm sure there's a way I could prevent that. But all I really want is a way to get the current command. This isn't a long-running production tool, just a quickie. Oh well.

Comment: Yes, it prints every line of every file, but *why's that a bad thing?* As long as you get a timestamp on every line, that means you can pinpoint the time needed for every operation. If your `PS4` contains `${BASH_SOURCE}`, then you can focus in on the lines from the files you care about.

Comment: It's a bad thing in my case because (for instance, as I just discovered) sourcing `nvm.sh` takes ages, but each command inside there is fast -- there's just a ton of stuff going on. So yes, I get around 10k lines out of the `set -x` log, but then I have to analyze that. That's what led me to the trap-based idea.

Comment: If skipping over 10k lines (or, say, searching for the next line that doesn't contain `nvm.sh`) takes longer than typing this comment, I question your choice of tools.

Comment: Haha, fair enough. And I didn't think of the PS4 source-file-naming idea. That would help for sure.

Comment: Wait, 10k lines out of a bashrc?  And you wonder why it is slow?  You could comment out sections to narrow down the section that slows you logins so much.

Comment: With all the zsh compinit stuff, antigen, nvm.sh, ssh setup, fancy path and prompt manipulations and a bunch of other things, yup. And yes, I ended up with simple timers placed manually around significant sections. That narrowed things down quickly and has zero overhead when not in use.